# You dont have permission to use this command even tho my friend's id is mentioned

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am very new to coding but I was trying to make a command that only the selected user ids can use

Here's my code

```
const DiscordCommand = require('../../contracts/DiscordCommand')
const admins = ['445952068621041664','408507536791044096']
class OverrideCommand extends DiscordCommand {
  
  onCommand(message) {

    if(admins.includes(message.author.id)) {
    let args = this.getArgs(message).join(' ')

    
    if (args.length == 0) {
      return message.reply(`No command specified`)
    }

    this.sendMinecraftMessage(`/${args}`)

    message.reply(`\`/${args}\` has been executed`)
  
}
    else
      message.reply(`You dont have permissions to use this command!`)
  }
  
}
module.exports = OverrideCommand
```

The

`const admins = ['445952068621041664','408507536791044096']`
contains the user id's of the people who should be able to use the command, The first id is my 1st friends with user id *445952068621041664* it works fine but when my 2nd friend with user id *408507536791044096* uses the command it says "You don't have permission to use this command" Can someone help me with this thanks!

Comment: probably you have a mistype on your friend's id

Comment: Do console.log after the admins.include line and check if it's executed. My best guess is as @Cursed said `You mistyped your friend's ID` check that too. Also, You didn't open the `{` after  `else` but closed it anyway